# Perl GetOpt::Long multiple arguments with optional parameter

Tags: perl, parsing, parameters, arguments, getopt

this is my fist post on stackoverflow. :)

I'm trying to solve this scenario with GetOpt::Long.

./myscript -m /abc -m /bcd -t nfs -m /ecd -t nfs ...

-m is mount point and -t is type of file system (can be placed, but it is not mandatory).

```
  Getopt::Long::Configure("bundling");
  GetOptions('m:s@' => \$mount, 'mountpoint:s@' => \$mount,
             't:s@' => \$fstype, 'fstype:s@'  => \$fstype)
```

This is not right, i'm not able pair proper mount and fstype

```
./check_mount.pl -m /abc -m /bcd -t nfs -m /ecd -t nfs
$VAR1 = [
          '/abc',
          '/bcd',
          '/ecd'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'nfs',
          'nfs'
        ];
```

I need fill unspecified fstype e.g. with "undef" value.
the best solution for me would be get hash such as...

```
%opts;
$opts{'abc'} => 'undef'
$opts{'bcd'} => 'nfs'
$opts{'ecd'} => 'nfs'
```

Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: You're trying to enforce a very specific order for options, but I don't think that's very common or intuitive. If I were a user of your application, I would expect `-m foo -t bar` to be the same as `-t bar -m foo`. You might be able to do this with Getopt::Long, but I think a different design would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be easy to do with `Getopt::Long` directly, but if you can change the argument structure a bit, such as to

```
./script.pl --disk /abc --disk /mno=nfs -d /xyz=nfs
```

...the following will get you to where you want to be (note that a missing type will appear as the empty string, not `undef`):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;

my %disks;

GetOptions(
    'd|disk:s' => \%disks, # this allows both -d and --disk to work
);

print Dumper \%disks;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '/abc' => '',
          '/mno' => 'nfs',
          '/xyz' => 'nfs'
        };
```

Comment: [You don't even need to `split` it yourself.](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Options-with-hash-values) Just beware of mount points containing `=`.

Comment: Good call @ThisSuitIsBlackNot... I've somehow missed that section of the docs in my years :) That's handy! (answer updated)

Answer (score 1):

From the "Argument callback" section of the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Parsing-options-from-an-arbitrary-string):

```
When applied to the following command line:
    arg1 --width=72 arg2 --width=60 arg3

This will call process("arg1") while $width is 80 , process("arg2") while $width is 72 , and process("arg3") while $width is 60.
```

---

**EDIT**: Add MWE as requested.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions :config permute);

my %mount_points;
my $filesystem;

sub process_filesystem_type($) {
    push @{$mount_points{$filesystem}}, $_[0];
}

GetOptions('t=s' => \$filesystem, '<>' => \&process_filesystem_type);

for my $fs (sort keys %mount_points) {
    print "$fs : ", join(',', @{$mount_points{$fs}}), "\n";
}
```

./test -t nfs /abc /bcd -t ext4 /foo -t ntfs /bar /baz

> ext4 : /foo
>
> nfs : /abc,/bcd
>
> ntfs : /bar,/baz

Note that the inputs are ordered as filesystem type then mountpoints. This is reversed from the OP's solution.

Comment: it would probably help tremendously if you provided a working example based off of the OPs question...

Comment: @stevieb I added the MWE, as requested. Probably should have done that before, but I was feeling lazy.